# Подключение css к html в Java

Tags: java, html, css, post

Не удается подключить css файл style.css, который находится в папке css, html его просто не видит.. Что в моем html может быть не так?

```
if(method.equals("GET")) {
    response = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
        "<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style.css\">" +
        "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">" +
        "<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=edge,chrome=1>" +
        "<title>Login Form</title>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<section class=\"container\">" +
        "<div class=\"login\">" +
        "<form method=\"POST\">\n" +
        "<section class=\"container\">\n" +
        "<div class=\"login\">\n" +
        "<h1>Login to Web App</h1>" +
        "\"<form method=\"POST\">\n" +
        "<p><input type=\"text\" name=\"login\" placeholder=\"Username or Email\"></p>\n" +
        "<p><input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\"></p>\n" +
        "<p class=\"remember_me\">\n" +
        "</p>" +
        "<p class=\"submit\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"commit\" value=\"Login\"></p>\n" +
        "</div>" +
        "</form> " +
        "</div>" +
        "</section>" +
        "</body></html>";
}
```

p.s. не через java все работает

Comment: Ты отдаешь html страничку с помощью твоего кода, также нужно отдавать стили и прочее.

Answer (score 0):

Простейший вариант открыть страницу в Debug режиме клавишей F12, на вкладке Networks посмотреть обращение к файлу css/style.css должно быть что то типа статус 200 или 302. по итогам этого правьте код.

ЗЫ возможно стоит поменять css/style.css на /css/style.css

Comment: В InteliJ видимо нет такой опции..

Comment: @ValekPotapov это в браузере. Загружаете страницу, потом нажимаете F12.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить тебе альтернативу твоему "ужасному коду")))

Рассмотри [вот этот вопрос и ответы к нему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952103/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-html-css-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-java/952260#952260)

Личная рекомендация: я бы реализовывал бы сайт на Java с помощью Spring + Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if(method.equals("GET")) {
>     response =
> ```

А кто url проверять будет?

Ты сейчас на все get-запросы отдаёшь одну и ту же страницу, а надо за запросы за css и js отдавать их, а не её.

Comment: Типа под каждый ресурс проверять адрес?