# Как создавать HTML (+ CSS) страницы в Java?

Tags: java, html, css

Интересует библиотека по созданию HTML с добавлением в него данных через переменные (Что-то вроде [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/index.html) или [HTMLFlow](https://github.com/xmlet/HtmlFlow)). Не с помощью SPRING и без Apache Tomcat! Сервер написан с использованием [HttpServer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950788/275232).

Предположим, у меня есть заготовленный HTML+CSS шаблон сайта и я хотел бы в него вставлять данные, сохранять страницу и выставлять ее потом на сайте.

Вот пример шаблона:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <h2></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Вместо `<h1>`и `<h2>` я хотел бы ставить `Hello` и `World` сответственно.

Если возможен вариант решения через Thymeleaf - то я очень приветствую ибо в интернете в основном Thymeleaf идет со Spring'ом.

P.S. Пример кода - это сугубо пример. В моем случае нужно это мне для создания таблицы-расписания.

Comment: `java ee` пробовали?

Comment: @michael_best в ней можно создавать html страницы?

Comment: Для таких целей испльзуется back end в лице PHP.

Comment: @Алексей не обязательно. Bac end может быть реализован на любом языке. В том числе и Java. У меня сервер на Java написан.

Comment: Html страницы должны быть определены как статика, в которой заполняются переменные. Грубо говоря, можно даже через String.replace

Comment: да, можно. для этого создаете файлы с расширение `jsp`, и наполняете `html` кодом.

Comment: @michael_best можно пример кода?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAma_mKffTOTTFqIkLXgHqVuL6xJhb0mr

Comment: @michael_best без Tomcat не работает...

Comment: А.... это я плохо посмотрел, извиняюсь

Comment: сейчас что-нибудь поищу

Comment: @michael_best ничего, я забыл добавить инфу по серверу в свой ответ) Я учту вариант с JSP! Но мне просто хочется генерировать `html` файлы...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90552/discussion-between-michael-best-and-antonio112009).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дополнение к ответу [Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/952260/275232):

**Расположение *.java и *.html файлов у вас может отличаться!**
Данный пример для Maven-юзеров

Визуализация файлов в проекте:

```
 .
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── Demo.java
        └── resources
            └── test.html
```

Создаем файл `Demo.java`:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

public class Demo{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("h1", "Hello");
        context.setVariable("h2", "World");
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        templateEngine.process("test.html", context, stringWriter);
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
    }
}
```

Создаем HTML-файл в папке `resources/` с именем `test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${h1}"></h1>
<h2 th:text="${h2}"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если вы убрали пакет, то и структура каталогов должна измениться. Ну, index.html может просто лежать в одном каталоге с Demo.java, если не используется Maven.

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.example;

import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("h1", "Hello");
        context.setVariable("h2", "World");
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        templateEngine.process("test.html", context, stringWriter);
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает. Это для Спринга код?

Comment: Нет, это обычное консольное приложение. Что именно значит "не работает"?

Comment: выдает ошибку. добавлю скрин в вопрос

Comment: В ошибке написано, что файл test.html не найден в classpath.

Comment: Можешь приложить, пожалуйста, тогда HTML файл? У меня файл test.html есть (уже в разных папках проекта создавал его)

Comment: https://github.com/TheDeadOne/thymeleaf-console-render

Comment: Все заработало! Спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на Apache FreeMarker https://freemarker.apache.org/
Будет необходимо определить html-template, с переменными, которые будут подставляться из Java-кода. По аналогии с JSP